# recover Windows

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC using USB drive.

After intalling Ubuntu-GNOME 13.04 I went and opened the app "Disks" and clicked on the 1st Disk Drive and then on the right side I clicked on the "File System Partition" and by mistake I clicked the button "More Action" and did something and I lost my Windows OS, but I have all the Data , I can see it from Ubuntu file explorer.

When i started my pc after my blunder (wehich I didn't know at the time). It automatically boot into Ubuntu .. and not Windows. :(
Please Help Me .. I don't know what to do now .

Answer (score 0):

You probably overwrote the boot sector. I say this based on the fact that you say you can still see all your files.

What you need to do is restore it.

If you have a Windows Installation DVD available (and you are running Windows 7), then follow the instructions found at [this How-To-Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/).  That will leave you with a computer that boots into Windows normally. Please be especially careful while performing these steps, since if you mistakenly click the wrong thing a second time, you risk losing your files.

If you do not have a Windows installation DVD available, Or you use some other version of Windows please update your question to let us know, and somebody can probably provide an answer for that case.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this out it contains all the informations about [how to restore boot loader](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-restore-grub-boot-loader-after-installing-windows.html) an if in case you just want to get your data back you can check this [Windows data Recovery software](http://www.recoverdatatools.com/Windows-Data-Recovery-Software.html) and if my answer seems helpful to you plz vote :P